# Retrieve Block number and Transaction Id from query to Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I'm new to hyperledger fabric and I'm trying to query a chaincode for a specific key. I can retrieve the json data for the key but I would also like to get the block number and transaction id related to the last PutState call which created/updated the data I'm retrieving from couchDB. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Responding to help anyone who could have the same problem and to check if the solution I adopted makes any sense. So as I understand Hyperledger allows you to get the transaction id before your transaction is submitted to the blockchain wich I found peculiar after having worked with ethereum. Using golang me and my colleagues found this line:

```
txID :=  ctx.GetStub().GetTxID();
```

So our solution was to save the transaction id inside the data we are storing in the blockchain, to easily retrieve it by a simple query (to couchDB for example).
In the end we retrieved the informations bound to the txid by calling the "GetBlockByTxID" sc of the "qscc" chaincode (present by default in every channel of hyperledger as far as I understand) using the "fabric-network" node module, and decoded it using "fabric-common" node module's BlockDecoder:

```
  result = BlockDecoder.decode(result)
```