# How to query/know in Hyperldger Fabric to know when a chaincode method was executed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a Hyperledger 1.4 version blockchain network running. My chaincode has a special method to fix some data which was executed only once. I need to query the ledger to check when that method was executed (it was executed as I did execute it using the CLI node) but I need to somehow "prove" that it was executed and the data was actually fixed. How can I perform that query or check (not just checking peer node logs but actually checking using the blockchain history)

(Just to clarify more: I don't want to query the data in the blockchain, I did that already using a query method and the data is correct and fixed.)

Answer (score 0):

At the time of running the update, get the Transaction ID and use it to query the blockfile later on. This thread might provide some more information
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67263579/retrieve-block-number-and-transaction-id-from-query-to-hyperledger-fabric)

I am presuming that any history that you may wish to view is not taken from the World State database but that you want to see what was written to the blockfile.

Comment: Exactly, but I don't have the transaction ID, just the executed "method" name of the chaincode (I already executed the mehtod and didn't save the transaciton ID). Anyway to find what is the transaction ID for that execution?

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario I would emit an event from smart contract itself. Within your method you can include something like:

```golang
// golang smart contract
func (c *Contract) SomeMethod(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface) error {
     
    // some logic

    // Emit the an event
    someEvent := new(SomeEvent)
    someEvent.field1 = "123"
    someEvent.field2 = "345"

    someEventBytes, err := json.Marshal(someEvent)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal someEventBytes: %v", err)
    }

    err = ctx.GetStub().SetEvent("MethodExec", someEventBytes)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to SetEvent someEventBytes %s: %v", someEventBytes, err)
    }

    return err
}
```

You would need to have a client app that listen and captures that event:

```js
// js client app
  contract.addContractListener(async (event) => {
    const { eventName, payload } = event;
    console.log(`chaincode ${eventName} trigger detected`);

    const data = JSON.parse(payload.toString('utf-8'));
    const { field1, field2 } = data;

     // do something with field1, field2
  });
```

More info on events [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-1.4/tutorial-listening-to-events.html#:%7E:text=There%20are%20three%20event%20types,automatically%20when%20a%20block%20is).

Comment: What if the method is already executed and I can't execute it again? Can I take this approach?

Comment: @icordoba So, this will work from the time you implement it forward. It will emit an event anytime the smart contract it's invoked. If you mean past executions, then no. For that case, the only option you got is to have a query that checks past transactions. The ledger is an actual history log of cc executions. You said you don't want to use queries, but I dont see another way.

Comment: Thanks. My problem on past transactions is that I don't have that past transactionId to do a query per transacitonId... and looks like no way to find it.